# Using window.print() in angular 2 print only one page

Tags: javascript, css, angular

I put the html for print in a `div` with class `forPrint` which is in a material dialog page and call the `window.print()` when the print button is clicked in the angular component.
However, it shows/prints only the page in the current screen and the rest is cut off when the button is clicked.
How to print the whole content in the div with class forPrint?
I think the reason is material dialog because when I print something in a normal page it works fine.

CSS:

```
@media print {
    /deep/ body * { visibility: hidden; }
    /deep/ .forPrint * { visibility: visible; display:block;}
    /deep/ .forPrint { display:block;position: absolute; top: 40px; left: 30px; } 

}
```

Comment: it may have something to do with `position: absolute;` and only supplying top/left ... add `bottom:40px; right:30px;` (I'm assuming you've done the above to add margins to the printed document)

Comment: I think the reason is the material dialog, because when I print something in a normal page it works fine

Answer (score 1):

To print whole content of class-forPrint or page use below CSS

```
@media print {
      body, html, .forPrint{
          width: 100%;
          height:100%;
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had such a problem when used material sidenav. Try create forPrint div beyond sidenav container.